# Cannot get sewn clothes to conform to 3d body model

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image: Clothing poking through base model]

I have recently started doing modding for Skyrim legendary edition and have imported the female nif file to use as a base when creating clothes, however, whenever I try and run the simulation, the clothes have this clipping issue as seen in the picture. I have tried messing around with the cloth settings, but things just got worse. I can provide more pictures upon request. In addition, is this body okay for using? Or would I need to get a different one to model my clothes on? My goal is to inject these clothes into the Skyrim game.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Thanks.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=OzwaOdJ8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/OzwaOdJ8/)
Here is the file that I am currently working on, the clothes will adhere to the model, but there is still clipping. I am not sure how to fix it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

- Uncheck "Single Sided" in the Collision modifier for the bra.
- Removed doubles and loose vertices on cloth.
- Subdivided cloth for more resolution.
- Increased Quality Steps under Cloth and Collisions in the cloth settings to 10.
- Reduced Tension to allow the cloth to stretch which prevented the cloth from slipping off.

---

[image]